# F# object refer to self in let bindings before members

Tags: f#

Is it possible for an object to refer to itself before member definitions? Something like this:

```
type public ClassA () = class
    let b = new ClassB(this)
    member public x.getClassB() = b
    end
```

where 'this' is a reference to the instance of ClassA creating the ClassB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Classes can refer to themselves in their constructors using `as`:

```
type public ClassA () as this = 
    let b = new ClassB(this)
    member public x.getClassB() = b
and public ClassB (a: ClassA) =
    member public x.getClassA() = a
```

Comment: In this example (or a simpler one), is there any difference between using `x` and `this`?

Comment: @torbonde `x` defines the 'self' property for the members, whereas `this` has constructor scope.  You must always have a 'self' property for members, but you can omit the self-identifier for the constructor.

Comment: For clarity, both the constructor-level self identifier ('this' in the example above) and the member level one ('x') can be any otherwise unused label.

E.g.:

type public ClassA () as foo = 
    let b = new ClassB(foo)
    member public bar.getClassB() = b
and public ClassB (a: ClassA) =
    member public bar.getClassA() = a

Comment: ...and you can 'effectively' omit the self-identifer for methods by using __ - e.g. type public ClassA () as foo = 
    let b = new ClassB(foo)
    member public __.getClassB() = b
and public ClassB (a: ClassA) =
    member public __.getClassA() = a